# EntityFramework Change Tracking not tracking changes

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am using Entity Framework 7 and I need to be able to track changes. I am ultimately doing something like this during the on SaveChanges I am overriding it then at the end using base.SaveChanges():

```
foreach (var ent in this.ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(p => p.State == EntityState.Deleted || p.State == EntityState.Modified).ToList())
{
    // For each changed record, get the audit record entries and add them
    foreach (TableChange x in GetTableChangeRecordsForChange(ent, _ChangeUser))
    {
        this.TableChanges.Add(x);
        val = true;
    }
}
```

This ultimately calls out to get table change records:

```
private IEnumerable<TableChange> GetTableChangeRecordsForChange(EntityEntry dbEntry, string userId)
{
    List<TableChange> result = new List<TableChange>();    
    foreach (var ent in this.ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(p => p.State == EntityState.Deleted || p.State == EntityState.Modified).ToList())
    {
        // For each changed record, get the audit record entries and add them
        foreach (TableChange x in GetTableChangeRecordsForChange(ent, _ChangeUser))
        {
            this.TableChanges.Add(x);
            val = true;
        }
    }

    if (dbEntry.State == EntityState.Modified)
    {
        foreach (var property in dbEntry.Entity.GetType().GetTypeInfo().DeclaredProperties)
        {

            // For updates, we only want to capture the columns that actually changed
            if (!object.Equals(dbEntry.Property(property.Name).OriginalValue, dbEntry.Property(property.Name).CurrentValue))
            {
                 result.Add(new TableChange()
                 {
                       Action = "U",
                       ColumnName = property.Name,
                       CreatedBy = userId,
                       CreatedOn = DateTime.Now,
                       OldValue = dbEntry.Property(property.Name).OriginalValue.ToString(),
                       NewValue = dbEntry.Property(property.Name).CurrentValue.ToString(),
                       TableName = dbEntry.Entity.GetType().GetTypeInfo().Name,
                       TableID = dbEntry.Property("ID").CurrentValue.ToString()
                       });
              }

          }
    }
}
```

Now the issue that I am facing is both OriginalValue & CurrentValue and the new value that was entered. It is not tracking what the original value was.

I do have:

```
this.ChangeTracker.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = true;
```

Yet I am still not getting it to provide me the original and current value correctly. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: the code you posted does not help much to debug this problem. The problem here is before you obtaining the `dbEntry`. It should involve some entity which is very important to know if it should be tracked correctly or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I figured out my own issue... the issue I was facing was I was attaching the record that needed updating. I ultimately updated the record by creating my Update Function:

```
public T ADMSUpdate<T>(T entity, T originalEntity)
    {
        object propertyValue = null;
        PropertyInfo[] properties = originalEntity.GetType().GetProperties();
        foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
        {
            propertyValue = null;
            if (null != property.GetSetMethod())
            {
                PropertyInfo entityProperty = entity.GetType().GetProperty(property.Name);
                propertyValue = entity.GetType().GetProperty(property.Name).GetValue(entity, null);

                if (null != propertyValue)
                {
                    property.SetValue(originalEntity, propertyValue, null);
                }
            }
        }
        return entity;
    }
```